# media library not showing images on wordpress 2018

Tags: wordpress

I've 4.9.5 version of Wordpress. it was working fine but i tried to upload a post and i see that images are not showing in media library and also i'm not able to upload media it's showing 'An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.' error.

I've already googled but not got any fix. read some questions in Stack Overflow.

I've also tried to disable all plugins and also themes but got nothing.

Don't mark it as duplicate because I've checked all solutions that provided in those questions.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by myself. I just replace database file with my backup and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check few things: 
check write permission for uploads folder
check if you have any functions that restricting particular image extensions at functions.php

Comment: i've set 744 permission

Comment: did you try 775?

Comment: switch to any default theme(twentyseventeen) and check, if you can upload the images, then the problem is on your theme. Now start checking functions.php, wp-config, htacess and disabling plugins.

But if you can't upload image on default theme too, then check your server config.

Comment: i think you didn't read question well. I already wrote it that I've tried to disable theme and plugin both.